# Best practice: Foreign key to reference certain revision of element

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, orm, relational-database

I'm looking for a "best practice" implementation of this scenario:

Assume you have an inventory table listing certain items. These items can be ordered and there needs to be a table of archived orders where these elements are referenced (via foreign keys).

If the items now change, let's say their price or description changes, then this change would mess up the archived orders, because they would reflect current prices and not the ones that were used at the time of making the order.

So what is considered "best practice" to implement this?

- Just copy all information from the inventory table to the order archive table and don't reference anything
- Make new entries into the inventory table whenever there is an update and never overwrite anything, then reference "old" oversions
- Save older revisions of the inventory in a separate history table and reference this

All of these solutions come with drawbacks, is there anything I miss or is there really no "elegant" solution?

Comment: Might be worth looking into using a database engine that supports sql-2011 temporal tables. That would let you query the inventory table as it existed at a given order timestamp.

Comment: Legally if your company accepts an order having quoted prices, specification, Ts&Cs to the customer, you are bound to deliver to it (barring _force majeure_). So you'd darn better record what you quoted, even if you later realise it was a mistake. Best practice (in ERPs) is yes to copy inventory details to the order/archive. It's very likely anyway that pricing/discounting is specific to this order/this customer. Less critical attributes you might put in an inventory history table. See temporal database, as @Shawn says.